# Oxygen depriving gas/compound

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

A scene from the movie TENET made me think of a question. In the scene a gas is released into a room that is filled with precious artwork. The gas is used to rid of all oxygen in the room so fire cannot enter the facility. What kind of gas would be used to "gobble up" oxygen? Assuming there is no ventilation system to push the oxygen out, is there a gas/compound that can rapidly absorb or destroy oxygen atoms? Thank you!

Comment: Such reactions that remove oxygen do so with the release of a lot of energy, usually as heat. This does artworks no good at all.

Comment: yea, you can purge the room with $N_{2}$ or some other inert gas. Maybe the addition of an oxygen scrubber will reduce $O_{2}$ levels.

Comment: Not a gas, but a solid can do that. apparently: https://phys.org/news/2014-09-material-oxygen-air.html . Leaves me a bit sceptical though. Why isn't it a world-renowned success story, if it really works?

Comment: The easiest, quickiest, cheapest and most efficient thing to do is to purge the room with nitrogen $\ce{N_2}$

Comment: @Maurice, it sounds like this guy wants something that *reacts* with oxygen, not that chases it away mechanically.

Comment: EDIT: yes I am looking for a chemical that reacts with oxygen.

Comment: Well, one is the powder I referred to above, if we believe it. Then, I just looked up my old Vogel's Practical Organic Chemistry. Apparently alkaline solutions of pyrogallol, and Fieser's solution, can be used to scrub small quantities of oxygen from a gas stream. For your case, removing the oxygen in a whole room, especially by another gas, I think we are in the realm of science fiction. Otherwise it would be the perfect crime :).

Comment: In fact hydrogen can react with oxygen, so yes, you could inject some hydrogen in the room and then ignite it. Not sure it would be a very inconspicuous process, though, as pointed out by Waylander :)

Comment: Why is *displacing* the oxygen not considered? Put in dense halon at bottom, N2/O2 comes out the top. This is, indeed, the way server-room fire extinguishers operate.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : why? Original post: "Assuming there is no ventilation system to push the oxygen out".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Halon does more than displace oxygen. It is quite good at gobbling up reactive species and shutting down reaction paths. Done properly, a human should be able to breath in a room after a halon release, if sized properly.

Comment: Actually, I was at a site where they accidentally "tested" the halon server-room extinguishers while the glassed-in room was occupied. Though the over-pressure rather dramatically blew out the heavy windows, no one was badly injured (or suffocated).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we really shouldn’t be entertaining a question based on such a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are commercial fire extinguishers that work by displacing the oxygen in a room. I forget the name but the safety experts put spheres containing an inert gas ( not a noble gas ,not CO2) to auto automatically be released in event of fire . Hydrogen was used in these lab rooms , but I don't know if that is why these extinguishes were chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, no exotic compound is required to consume the oxygen in a room, or, for example, a large sewer pipe.

In fact, an interesting report of workers who died when drainage occurred in a sewer pipe, resulting in the exposure of fresh iron metal surfaces, likely in the presence of acidic conditions and a complexing agent. A reaction pursed resulting in a significant consumption of the available oxygen.

Here is the underlying electrochemical reaction:

$\ce{ Fe (s) + O2 (g) + 2 H+ (aq) -> Fe(II) (aq) + 2 OH- (aq) }$

Source: See http://corrosion-doctors.org/Experiments/rust-chemistry.htm

Further, a corresponding reaction based on ferrous converting into ferric.

In the current context of the question, spraying a very fine mist of aqueous nano-iron particles, freshly mixed with an acid source, say CO2 or citric acid, may have a similar effect.

[EDIT] Here is [a citation from the CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/face/in-house/full8836.html) on the alluded to sewers workers deaths, to quote:

> On August 19, 1988, a 31-year-old male assistant construction supervisor (victim) entered an **oxygen-deficient** manhole to close a valve and collapsed at the bottom. In a rescue attempt a labor foreman (male, age 34) and the victim’s supervisor (male, age 36) also entered the manhole and also collapsed. All three workers were pronounced dead at the scene by the county coroner.

Per another [related report](https://www.baltimoresun.com/news/bs-xpm-2006-08-18-0608180132-story.html), to quote:

> In underground sewer holes, high levels of methane gas and **depletion of oxygen** are common, Sherman said.

Now, some may feel confident in dismissing electrochemical based oxygen depletion, but please note it is actually killing essential workers.

[EDIT 2] Did find an explicit report citing the action of rusting leading to oxygen consumption and a fatality in this [source addressing confined space accidents](https://www.safteng.net/index.php/34-incident-alert-archives/confined-space-accidents). To quote:

> The interior of the compartment was rusty, Kingsley noted, and there was standing water inside. "The chemical process of oxidation or rusting uses up oxygen, thereby creating an oxygen-poor atmosphere," she wrote. According to Workers' Compensation Board findings included in the report, the air in the Apex No. 1's other eight compartments contained 20.9-per-cent oxygen, which is in the normal range for the Earth's atmosphere. The sealed compartment's air was between 15.7 and 16.4 per cent oxygen -- low enough that it can't support human life for long.

Comment: Please cite why the documented reaction is not applicable here. Thanks. By the way, do not place your head in a vessel with such a wet iron metal mix to prove your point, as I am sure you will suffer oxygen deprivation.

Comment: In the case you cited the speculation  was that decomposition of organic matter (ie biological activity) was responsible for oxygen depletion. No where is it suggested that exposed iron was a factor.

Comment: Andrew: Yes, you are correct, but only in the references I was able to find recently with respect to the fact that Fe exposure is not explicitly mentioned. However, my original source did mention something about drainage and freshly exposed Iron surfaces which I immediately linked back to my claimed key electrochemical reaction. More recent sources above only affirm O2 consumption but not how.

Comment: Andrew: Was able to find a source confirming my essentially rusting-based electrochemical reaction. See [EDIT 2].